# Нужна ли запятая перед "нежели"?

Tags: пунктуация

Житков относился к Корнею Чуковскому скорее как к "драгоценному объекту для приложения своих педагогических талантов"  нежели как к другу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, нужна. Союз "нежели" (устар.) соответствует союзу "чем"

Answer (score 4):

Запятая нужна.

> НЕЖЕЛИ, союз. Книжн. Употр. для
> присоединения сравнительного оборота
> при наличии сравнительной степени
> прилагательного, наречия или слов
> "другой", "иначе" и т.п.; чем. Сегодня
> она была одета по-иному, **нежели** вчера.
> Иванов объясняет лучше, **нежели** Петров.

[link text](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%ED%E5%E6%E5%EB%E8&all=x)

> НЕЖЕЛИ, союз
>
> Синтаксические конструкции,
> начинающиеся с союза «нежели»,
> выделяются знаками препинания, обычно
> запятыми.
>
> Жизнь его, сколько я знаю, проходит в
> большей пустоте, **нежели** жизнь Левки,
> который, чего нет другого, гуляет, а
> тот все сердится. А. Герцен, Доктор
> Крупов. Я, может быть, более, **нежели**
> всякий другой, имею право на этот
> портрет. Н. Гоголь, Портрет. Но помня
> более о вашей опасности, **нежели** о моей
> обиде и о жестокосердии начальника с
> его подчиненным, я побежал к
> караульной, которая была версты с две
> расстоянием от проклятого дома, из
> которого меня вытолкнули. А. Радищев,
> Путешествие из Петербурга в Москву.

[link text](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_468)

Comment: А что должна подтвердить или опровергнуть первая цитата?  
Ну вторая хоть дает прямой ответ на вопрос...

Comment: В словарных статьях зачастую приводятся не только значения слов, но и примеры употребления и расстановки знаков препинания. На эти примеры можно опираться в своих рассуждениях по поводу, например, расстановки знаков. Что и демонстрирует первая цитата. Странно, что вы этого не знали.

Comment: А вы разве **мне** отвечали? И почему я вдруг что-то должен знать? 
Да и не в этом дело. Если действительно какой-то смысл есть в цитате, обычно об этом говорят сразу...  
Странно, что вы этого не знали ©

Answer (score 2):

Запятая, конечно, нужна. Увы, но внятного общего объяснения этому я не нашел.
Вряд ли, конечно, здесь срабатывает принцип замены "нежели" на "чем" - этот прием вообще далеко не всегда работает, а тут ещё и значения не совсем совпадают.
Еще более странно видеть объяснение в отсылке к БТС(!) Кузнецова, где даже семантика дается весьма расплывчато.
Боюсь, в данном случае не остаётся ничего другого, как просто запомнить. Для конкретного случая, когда есть прямое противопоставление "скорее как к ...., нежели к".
Опасно это тем, что несколько примеров без запятой в нацкорпусе (Гиппиус, Бунин, Лермонтов) могут ввести в большой конфуз.

Comment: Нацкорпус не предназначен для проверки пунктуации. У него другие задачи.

Comment: Спасибо, очень ценное неблюдение. )))
Но он очень удобен для проверки сомнительных утверждений.

Comment: Это не наблюдение — знание предмета разговора.

Comment: Вас не обидит, еслди я спрошу, а вы на какую тему сечас разговариваете?  
И с кем?